Can I change which keys control windows resize when in the `begin_resize` mode
There is a keyboard shortcut (default is <Alt+F8>) for resizing a window. Specifically, I am referring to this configuration option: org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin_resize.
By default, the arrow keys control resizing the window. Can I change which keys control resizing the window once I am in the resize mode? I can't seem to find any related setting in donf-editor.

A good question for whom ever makes org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin_resize thing.
